# Sorting a list of pairs so that the larger number in the pair appears first

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Imagine I have this data.

[image: data]

I want to sort it so that it takes the form:

```
{{<larger>, <smaller>}, {<larger>, <smaller>}, ...},
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `Map[ReverseSort]@list` or  `ReverseSort/@list`?

Answer (score 3):

```
lists = {{0.959531`,1.72455`},{1.39025`,1.70444`},{1.53595`,0.207495`}, 
  {0.117589`,0.270531`},{0.815728`,1.53551`},{1.43189`,0.0795958`}, 
  {0.959939`,0.742054`},{1.92875`,1.77258`},{0.494335`,0.588112`}, 
  {1.22158`,1.08751`},{0.8228`,0.309531`},{1.41939`,0.833903`}}


MatrixForm[lists]
```

[image]

```
 sorted = Map[ReverseSort] @ lists;

 MatrixForm[sorted]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, some of the `0`s get read as `@` by `TextRecognize` on my machine (12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)).
Also it is a bit ironic that `TextRecognize` does not recognize Mathematica output.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sort[#, Greater] & /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 6}, {3.14, π}}
```

Or

```
{{1, 2}, {3, 3}, {5, 6}, {3.14, π}} /. {x_?NumberQ, 
   y_?NumberQ} :> {Max[x, y], Min[x, y]}
```

> {{2, 1}, {3, 3}, {6, 5}, {π, 3.14}}